# Uploading and linking a blob to pimcore-Assets via JavaScript inside a Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, blob, pimcore

I'm having a pimcore-Plugin where I'm trying to upload a blob to the pimcore-Assets via JavaScript. Not enough I want to link this Asset to the href-field of an open object.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've played around with the save-function inside `/pimcore/static/js/pimcore/asset/asset.js` but I don't see the hook.